# How can I query the value of an object rather than the key value pair in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express

I've store an array on my user object which holds all of the data

```
{
   _id: ObjectId(#############)
   fname: 'Bob',
   lname: 'Vargas',
   data: [
     // the data I want
   ]
}
```

I am using express to get his data like this:

```
db.users.findOne( { _id: ObjectId(#############) }, { data: 1, _id: 0 } );
```

but that is giving me an object rather than the array:

```
{ data: [  /* my data */ ]}
```

**how can I get just the array?**

UPDATE

```
app.get('/user/:id/data', function (req, res, next) {
    db.users.findOne(
        { _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
        { data: 1, _id: 0 },
        function (err, userData) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(userData); 
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: `how can I get just the array?` what is your expected result from the find? Is it `{data : []}` or just the `[]` ?

Comment: I just want the `[]`. I'm getting `{ data: [] }`

Comment: That is not possible at all. You will get `{data:[]}` only from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's `findOne()` will only return an object, not an array; thus the `One`. Instead you will need to receive it as and object and then get the value.

If you are doing this from mongo shell then there is no way around unless you want to move the data into its own collection. Otherwise you can get the array from the object in your application.

UPDATE:

in your express response, only encode the data value, like this

```
res.json(userData.data);
```

Comment: I'm using Express to get it, but in the form of an observable, so I'm having trouble accessing just the value.

Answer (score 2):

Add projection to query result:

```
db.users.findOne( { _id: ObjectId(#############) }, {_id:0, data:1} )
```

Use `0` to exlude field from result (`_id` is included by default), and `1` to include field in result.

MongoDB returns object per document. But you can manually map objects on client side:

```
db.users.findOne( { _id: ObjectId(#############) }, {_id:0, data:1} )
        .map(function(d){ return d.data; }))
```

Comment: sorry, i have that but left it out. I'm still getting the `data` key

Comment: @bob mongo returns object per document. You can only process query results